# The name 'Units' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'lineseries' - in getframe

Tags: matlab, plot

How to capture plot image into memory? I am trying to use `getframe`, but failing

```
>> plot(h)
>> myhandle=plot(h)

myhandle =

  174.0044

>> myframe=getframe(myhandle)
Error using graph2d.lineseries/get
The name 'Units' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'lineseries'.

Error in getframe>Local_getRectanglesOfInterest (line 138)
  if ~strcmpi(get(h, 'Units'), 'Pixels')

Error in getframe (line 56)
  [offsetRect, absoluteRect, figPos, figOuterPos] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the MATLAB doc found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html

```
F = getframe(h) gets a frame from the figure or axes identified by handle h.
```

When I do handle=plot(......), then type get(handle), and look at the type, you will see it is indeed a line series object, not an axis or figure.

To do what you want, use `getframe(gca)` or `getframe(gcf)`. gca/gcf = getCurrentAxes/Figure respectively.

To be honest though, unless you are doing a semi complicated GUI or something like that, getframe really doesn't usually need any input arguments.